# Laravel Select Query within helper file

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, laravel

I'm coming from codeigniter background. Unlike codeigniter helper directory, i just created helper directory within app directory of Laravel. Just want to know how to execute query within this common function. Here is my codeigniter function.

```
function show_menu($primary_key_col, $parent_id, $sort_order) 
{
$output = "";
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->db->select("*");
$ci->db->where('is_active', "Y");
$ci->db->where('is_delete', "N");
$ci->db->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
($sort_order!="")?$ci->db->order_by($sort_order, "ASC"):"";
$query = $ci->db->get('tbl_cms_menus');

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
    $output .= '<option value="'.$row->$primary_key_col.'">'.$indent.$row->menu_name.'</option>';
}
return $output; 
}
```

I tried something like this in laravel file. but this code did't give me any result. Please tell me where i'm doing wrong in this code. thanks

```
function databaseTable()
{
   $table = DB::table('tbl_cms_menus');
   $get_rows = $table->get();
   $count_rows = $table->count();

   if($count_rows > 0){
    foreach ($get_rows as $tbl)
    {
        echo $tbl->menu_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "please convert it into laravel" is not going to get you any help. At least put in some effort and try.

Comment: Just give me idea how to execute query within this helper file. thanks

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Answer (score 0):

This code will rot so hard that it shipped pre-rotten.

But, if you want to just.. ram it into the app all dry like that.. then add something like this to your base controller class...

```
$whatever = crazyChainingStuff;
foreach ($whatever ...) { $topMenu .= ... }
View::share('topMenu', $topMenu);
```

If you want to learn how to write code that will do less damage to your company and your clients then I recommend starting by watching Uncle Bob's "Fundamentals" videos. At least the first 5-6. http://cleancoders.com

Comment: is it possible to just return a string have with some data? just like this one:

Comment: <code>function databaseTable()
{
    $table = DB::table('tbl_cms_menus');
    $get_rows = $table->get();
    $count_rows = $table->count();
    
    if($count_rows > 0){
        foreach ($get_rows as $tbl)
        {
            echo "<pre>"; $tbl->menu_name; echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
}</code>   it's not working on my end.

Comment: If you want further help, you should hire a programmer.

Comment: I just edit my quest. Please give me answer accordingly. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to generate a `drop-down/select` with some data from your database, in this case, you should pass the data required for the `drop-down/select` from your controller to the view where you have written your `HTML`, for example, in your view, you may have a `select` like this:

```
echo Form::select('cms_menu', $cms_menu, Input::old('cms_menu'));
```

Or this (If you are using `Blade`):

```
{{ Form::select('cms_menu', $cms_menu, Input::old('cms_menu')) }}
```

From your `controller` you should pass the `$cms_menu` which should contain the `menu-items` as an arrtay and to populate that array you may try something like this:

```
$menuItems = DB::table('tbl_cms_menus')->lists('menu_name','id');
return View::make('your_view_name', array('cms_menu' => $menuItems));
```

Also, you may use something like this:

```
// Assumed you have a Page model
$menuItems = Page::lists('menu_name', 'id');
return View::make('your_view_name', array('cms_menu' => $menuItems));
```

You may also read [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout#.UznwCPmSySo) which is about building a menu from database using `view composer` (More Laravelish way). Read more about `Form::select` on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists).

Answer (score 0):

It was too late to give an answer. I was also from CodeIgniter background and when I learnt Laravel then first I try to find how can I write a query in Helper. My Team leader helped me.

I have converted your code in a helper function.

```
function show_menu($primary_key_col, $parent_id, $sort_order) 
{               
    $query = DB::table('tbl_cms_menus')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('is_active', '=', 'Y')
                ->where('is_delete', '=', 'N')
                ->where('parent_id', '=', $parent_id);
    ($sort_order != "")? $query->orderBy($sort_order, "ASC") : "";
    $resultData = $query->get()->toArray();

}
```

Here `$resultData` will be array format. Now, you can create a `foreach` loop according to your requirement.